# VB.Net detect keydown on control before keydown on form event

Tags: vb.net

I have enabled the KeyPreview option on the form and on the keydown of the form I am detecting  the Escape keydown to popup a msgbox requesting whether the user wants to exit from the application.

But the problem is, I have one textbox that needs to clear its contents on Escape keypress rather than asking whether the user needs to exit. And I tried using the keydown event on this control but the form keydown event occurs before the control keydown (I want this to happen the other way around).

**Code on the Textbox**

```
    Private Sub txtAmount(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles txtAmount.KeyDown
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Escape Then
            '//Escape keypress
            MsgBox("TEXTBOX ESCAPE")
            sender.Text = ""
        End If
    End Sub
```

**Code used on the Main menu Form**

```
    Private Sub frmMainMenu_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Escape Then Application.Exit()
    End Sub
```

I can't use the previewkeydown either because the MaskTextBox doesn't raise the previewkeydown event..

Answer (score 3):

Check if txtAmount is focused in the Form_KeyDown:

```
    Private Sub txtAmount_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles txtAmount.KeyDown
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Escape Then
            '//Escape keypress
            MsgBox("TEXTBOX ESCAPE")
            sender.Text = ""
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub frmMainMenu_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
        If txtAmount.Focused Then Return
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Escape Then Application.Exit()
    End Sub
```

Edit: Alternatively, if you don't want to specify each control individually, you could do it by type:

```
    If TypeOf Me.ActiveControl Is MaskTextBox Then Return
```

Or even more simpler, change your Form_KeyDown-Event to a KeyUp Event.

```
Public Class frmMainMenu
    Private KeyHandled As Boolean

    Private Sub txtAmount_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles txtAmount.KeyDown
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Escape Then
            sender.Text = ""
            KeyHandled = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub frmMainMenu_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
        KeyHandled = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub frmMainMenu_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyUp
        If KeyHandled Then Return
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Escape Then Application.Exit()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: isn't there a better workaround for this prob.. because I would have to add all the controls to be skipped on my frmMainMenu keydown..

Comment: The solution with `.Focused = True` let me explicitely set the places where a Hotkey should NOT be executed. Thanks for this idea @dummy

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code

```
Private Sub When_KeyDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyDown, MyBase.KeyDown
    If sender.name = "Your form name" Then
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Escape And Not TextBox1.Focused Then
            MsgBox("me")
        End If
    ElseIf sender.name = "your textBox name" Then
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Escape Then
            MsgBox("txt")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

I hope this can help you